# jquery replace the content of a #div with the contents of another #div?

Tags: jquery, html, replace

How Could I correctly replace the content of a div with the contents of another div?

- div1
- div2

I want the contents of div2 to be replacing the contents of div1

```
  $('#start').load('#start_hidden');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('#div2').html($('#div1').html());
```

Answer (score 5):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/M4v4M/

API: `.replaceWith` http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Hope it fit your need `:)`

**code**

```
$('#div2').replaceWith($('#div1').html());​
```